# Linq XML add new parent

Tags: c#, xml, linq

With linq XML is it possible to add a new father to existing nodes? 
Take this XML excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items>
 <book>
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <author>Author 1</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Title 2</title>
  <author>Author 2</author>
 </book>
 <car>
  <model>Tesla</model>
 </car>
</items>
```

Is it possible to add a new father "books" to book like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items>
 <books>
  <book>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <author>Author 1</author>
  </book>
  <book>
   <title>Title 2</title>
   <author>Author 2</author>
  </book>
 </books>
  <car>
   <model>Tesla</model>
  </car>
</items>
```

This is not working because it is cloning the nodes:

```
doc.Element("items").Add(new XElement("books",doc.Element("items").Elements("book")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your existed `<book>` elements from `<items>` node after adding them under new `<books>` parent node:

```
var books = doc.Element("items").Elements("book");
doc.Element("items").Add(new XElement("books", books));
books.Remove();
```